# Why was this flag declined?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged an answer as 'spam', because the content was something like

> I am Jeff. Jeff Jeff Jeff. etc

The post was deleted - yet my flag was declined. Why?

For 10k+ers: [Short-sighted and Near-sighted](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4405/short-sighted-and-near-sighted/339611#339611)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it is not selling or promoting a product or service. It's just a vague quote from a kid's book. "Not an answer" would be appropriate for this type of post.

It matters insofar as spam flags train our spam filter, which is why your flag was declined.

Comment: On other sites that I'm, they're always marked helpful, so I guess it was just surprising.

Comment: So the flag was declined because it was the wrong choice? 'Spam' has a fluid meaning, the one you game, but also leaning towards 'annoying irrelevant crap' (which is of course 'not an answer' also). The OP shouldn't be discouraged from flagging because of a reasonable choice. Can't you just approve for flagging if it helped mods deal with questions? (whether the flag reason was exactly perfect or not)

Comment: @Mitch We stick to a strict definition because it trains the spam filter. If it had been a different flag, I wouldn't have declined it.

Comment: Can you add something minimal to the flag descriptions to that effect?

Comment: @Mitch also, spam flags can lead to suspension. They really shouldn't be used lightly.

Comment: @terdon even more of a reason for warning on the spam reason.

Comment: @Mitch no, I can't, but I did just put our "how to flag" meta post as featured a couple of days ago. It describes that situation amongst others.

Comment: Coming back to this a year and a half later, I'll just point out that post content isn't considered at all for Stack Exchange's native spam filter; SpamRam works purely on IPs. Just for any future readers who may stumble across this :)